# What do you call a maker of wind instruments?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "a maker of wind instruments". Something to the same effect as a *luthier* to stringed instruments.

> The local *_*_ fixed the trombone as good as new.

Comment: [Brass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brass_instruments) and [woodwind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodwind)  are separate categories of instrument. You wouldn't expect there to be a single word for a person with (at least) two distinct sets of skills.

Comment: A "blowhard enabler"?

Comment: Your sample sentence has nothing to do with the title of your question. An instrument maker doesn't normally repair them. A trombone isn't a wind instrument. A musical instrument repair technician fixes trombones.

Comment: I've heard the term "Windsmith" used a few times to refer to someone who makes wind instruments, be they brass or woodwind. Not sure that the word actually exists, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. To be honest, I'm not sure if there is a specific word. Bagpipe players avail themselves of the services of a [pipemaker](http://www.mccallumbagpipes.com/); clarinet players go to a [clarinet maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_clarinet_makers), trumpet players to a [trumpet maker](http://www.trumpetguild.org/links/makers.htm), and so on.

Answer (score 3):

A maker of wind instruments, Casey Burns, calls himself an [artisan wind instrument maker](http://www.caseyburnsflutes.com/about.php).

There are several other sites that discuss these craftspersons, such as the book, [The Amateur Wind Instrument Maker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0870231189)

Answer (score 2):

I propose *ahenoficer* for the maker of brass instruments and *chalumier* (pronounced /ˈʃaly.mje/ from *chalumeau*, a 12th Century reed pipe) for the maker of woodwinds.

Those with more expertise in Latin and French might correct me.

**EDIT** a commentator with the disturbing name of Coleopterist urges me to make it explicit that these words are my own coinage; as far as I know, there is no synonym in current use.

**FURTHER EDIT:** Peter Shor reminds me of the Gallic inability to pronounce the last letter in any word and that /ʃalyˈmjɛʁ/ would only be the correct pronunciation for *chalumière*, a distaff maker of woodwinds.  Corrected.

Comment: If you're saying that there's no existing word for "a maker of wind instruments", please add that to your answer :)

Comment: I agree with @coleopterist. I think the O.P. was looking for an existing word, not asking us to make one up. (Neither of these are in any dictionary I checked, including the OED.) "I propose" perhaps suggests these are made up words, but only subtly.

Comment: That's not how you would pronounce *chalumier* in French. It'd be /ʃalyˈmje/, pronounced with the same ending as *boucher* (butcher) and *boulanger* (baker), and *chandelier* (candlestick maker). And if it were a female maker of wind instruments, it would be *chalumière,* pronounced  /ʃalyˈmjɛʁ/, to go with *boulangère*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently researching people who build unusual instruments for my PhD, and so far I haven't found any other word for "instrument builder" as widespread and popular as "luthier", or the "______ maker" for each specific instrument, neither in English nor in Portuguese or French, for that matter.

I have stumbled across the word "tambourier" for a drum maker, but am not sure whether it's actually used. Feeling Musique, a well-established wind instrument shop in Paris, for instance, uses "Luthier of wind instruments" as a term for the professionals who do this type of work.

Answer (score -2):

A reedmaker makes wind instruments.

Links:
http://rmhh.co.uk/occup/q-r.html

http://www.reedmaker.com/

http://aaronlakota.com/

http://www.reedmaker.com/products/oboe-reeds.html